# Python / pandas: compare several columns and create a new column each time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I have a huge table with hundreds of columns and I have to compare them in order to find out differences between 2 columns. The columns to compare can be easily be found by their suffixes "..._x" and "..._y". The first name is the same, only the suffix changes.

E.g.:

| cost_x | cost_y | amount_x | amount_y | type_x | type_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Every time I make a comparison a new column with the suffix "..._change" shall be created.

| cost_x | cost_y | amount_x | amount_y | type_x | type_y | cost_change | amount_change | type_change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | a | a | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | b | c | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Up to now I tried to do it with definitions in pandas:

```
def label_check1(row):
  if row['cost_x'] == row ['cost_y']:     return 1 
  return 0

def label_check2(row):
  if row['amount_x'] == row ['amount_y']:     return 1 
  return 0

def label_check3(row):
  if row['type_x'] == row ['type_y']:     return 1 
  return 0

result_df['cost_change'] = result_df.apply(label_check1, axis=1)
result_df['amount_change'] = result_df.apply(label_check2, axis=1)
result_df['type_change'] = result_df.apply(label_check3, axis=1)
```

By doing so it is maybe ok with 6 columns to compare, however, I have to compare app. 85 columns and I want to do it in some kind of loop or maybe in a UDF. The names of the columns are all known and I also have a list of them.

Does anybody have an idea of how to do it better with less code?

Answer (score 1):

Given the pattern of the columns, you can simply extract all the unique features (part before the underscore), and use a for loop to create new columns:

```
features = pd.Series(df.columns).apply(lambda s: s.split("_")[0]).unique()
# array(['cost', 'amount', 'type'], dtype=object)

for v in features:
    df[v+"_change"] = (df[v+"_x"] == df[v+"_y"]).astype(int)
```

This gives

```
   cost_x  cost_y  amount_x  amount_y  type_x  type_y  cost_change  amount_change  type_change
0       1       1         1         0       1       1            1              0            1
1       1       0         1         1       0       1            0              1            0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rework the columns as a MultiIndex, then slice `x` and `y` separately, compare them and `join` to the original DataFrame:

```
tmp = df.set_axis(df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True), axis=1).swaplevel(axis=1)

out = df.join(tmp['x'].eq(tmp['y']).astype(int).add_suffix('_change'))
```

Output:

```
   cost_x  cost_y  amount_x  amount_y  type_x  type_y  cost_change  amount_change  type_change
0       1       1         1         0       1       1            1              0            1
1       1       0         1         1       0       1            0              1            0
```